# I was on my way from Boston to Brockton and my engine light came on

Tags: engine, lights

I checked the gas cap and it’s fine. I called my mechanic who was too busy to talk to me and his assistant said it could be anything or nothing. I have to pick up my grandson in Norton from school and I’m afraid I’ll break down.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Page 129 of your owner's manual says that if the engine light is ***flashing***, further driving may damage your emission equipment. If the light is ***steady***, you should have the vehicle checked by a mechanic soon. The only likely harm when you have a steady engine light and you drive it for a few more days is to your fuel economy.

Your owner's manual:

[image: e]